# Azure B2C implementation redirection 404 issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Im trying to implement Azure AD B2C with Springboot app as mentioned in below documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-oidc?view=azure-java-stable

I tried exact steps. But once I click on userflow link, it is not able to redirect to the signup or sign-in screen. It is throwing 404 forbidden error page. Appreciate any references and help.

Thank you.

Comment: can you give the URL which takes you to 404 page? by using URL we can easily predict where it went wrong.

Comment: Hi Ramakrishna, here is the url:   https://phalguna.b2clogin.com/phalguna.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&scope=c8d1f150-96ce-4cb1-9746-4f6e8a3476da%20openid&state=QcGLdbQQxTukWHDp4jNYBS7ED5uRQIQK_KDwyXpyGFU%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/home

Comment: Your URL missing Policy name. Check the RunNow URL from Azure Portal B2C policy blade. **authorize?p=B2C_1_PolicyName**